# Why does operator in Protocol `need more context`?

Tags: swift, protocols

I have a protocol that only requires a `>` function. When I try to compare two objects that comform to the protocol I gives me a compiler error with the message "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context". I'd rather not require the function `isGreaterThan(...)` (or something) if I can avoid it, I'd rather stick to what people are used to using to compare (`>`).

So I have 2 questions. Why can't I do this? Is there a better way to do this, or a good workaround?

Thanks!

```
protocol Compare {
    func >(lhs: Compare, rhs: Compare) -> Bool
}


class TheClass {

    func hey(aCompare: Compare, theCompare: Compare) {
        if aCompare > theCompare {
            print("aCompare is greater than theCompare")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to interface with Swift's `>` operator here? In which case the protocol requirement should be `func >(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool`, and you should be using a generic parameter for your `hey` function. Although that being said, why aren't you using `Comparable` directly?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? is your `Compare` a `type`? Refer Operators in Swift https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html

Comment: Yes I am. Sorry, and thanks! I'll adjust the question.

Comment: And btw...who is confirming to your `protocol` and who is implementing your declared function in `protocol`? Read this doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Comment: It doesn't matter who conforms. That is the whole point.

Comment: To reiterate what @originaluser2 said: your protocol is no different to `Comparable` (except yours isn't defined properly) - why aren't you using that?

Comment: Apple's `Equatable` protocol does this actually. And that solved my answer.

Comment: @jrturton Ha, yes, that is very similar to what I want. I actually only want `>` `<` and `==`. But that solves my issue, I just need to use `Self` rather than the Protocol. My Bad...

Comment: I'll probably make a protocol that requires `>` and `<` and `inherits` from `Equatable`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the Protocol in the `>` operator, I should be using `Self` like Apple's `Equatable` and `Comparable` protocols.

```
protocol Compare {
    func >(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}


class TheClass {

    func hey(aCompare: Compare, theCompare: Compare) {
        if aCompare > theCompare {
            print("aCompare is greater than theCompare")
        }
    }

}
```

Now compiles.. Thanks @jrturton and @originaluser2